# web.config transforms - appSettings node does not transform

Tags: .net, web-config, appsettings, web-config-transform

I have got appSettings that i would like to share between multiple web applications. So at my root level for my solution, i created a folder "Common ConfigSettings". In here i have
all the common appSettings that gets shared. Then in the different web projects, i add a link to this file and reference the common settings like..

```
<appSettings file="../../Common ConfigSettings/sharedAppSettings.config">
```

This is working well while debugging. Now when I need to publish, the "linked" file is copied to the directory for the relevant web project, so the file path needs to change now, to point to same directory as the projects web.config . But i can't get the transform to work.

I am trying to transform the "file" attribute on the appSettings in my web.Config. But id does not seem to work.

**original web.config**

```
 <appSettings file="../../Common ConfigSettings/sharedAppSettings.config">
 </appSettings>
```

**transform**

```
<appSettings  file="sharedAppSettings.config"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(file)"   
</appSettings>
```

**then when i click preview transform**

```
 <appSettings file="../../Common ConfigSettings/sharedAppSettings.config">
 </appSettings>
```

Comment: Give your question a meaningful descriptive title, please.

Answer (score 4):

Got this working now. Just removed the "(file)" from the xdt:transform

**transform**

```
<appSettings file="sharedAppSettings.config"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes">
</appSettings>
```

**result**

```
<appSettings file="sharedAppSettings.config">
</appSettings>
```

thanks

Comment: Looking through, I realized I added xdt:Locator, but forgot to add xdt:Transform, too. Whoops :)